# Como sacar archivos de otra maquina desde mi app de c#

Tags: c#

Necesito que desde mi aplicacion, se conecte por ip a otra maquina y acceder a sus archivos.
Tengo esto en mi `app.config`, pero esto es solo de manera local, y necesito acceder a la otra maquina

```
<add key="Files" value="C:\XXXX\XX\XXXX\XXXXX\XXX\XXX" />
```

Y esto ya en mi codigo de la extraccion de datos, hago esto para obtener la direccion del folder en el APP(aqui deberia esta accediendo a la otra maquina)

```
string folder_Save = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Files"];
```

Solamente tengo esto, pero realmente quiero obtener esa informacion desde el app.config

```
`DirectoryInfo directorio = new DirectoryInfo("10.12.22.112." + "C:\\XXX\\XXX\\XX\\XXX`");
```

Comment: Qué falla? QUé error encuentras?

Comment: Realmente no hay errores aun, porque aun no se como hacer eso....edite la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Intenta mapeando los archivos remotos como una unidad de red o recurso compartido desde la PC donde ejecutas tu programa. Con esto los accedes con este formato: Para unidad compartida: "\\192.168.0.x\UnidadCompartida", para unidades mapeadas, igual que si fuera una unidad local: "p:\carpeta\". Recuerda colocar el verbatim  (@ ) para que no te de error de sintaxis.

Comment: esta es la respuesta a tu pregunta, sin embargo no funciona en net core.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/1197430#1197430

Answer (score -2):

Puedes seguir el mismo procedimiento que realizaste para acceder a la ruta de los archivos, defines una `key` en el *app.config* dentro de las etiquetas xml de `appSettings`:

```
<add key="Remoto" value="10.12.22.112"/>
```

Ahora bien, si estas utlizando Helpers para leer los settings puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
public static readonly string Remoto = GetValue<string>("Remoto");
```

O sino puedes realizarlo como lo has hecho para el directorio:

```
string ipRemoto = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Remoto"];
```

Luedo puedes utilizar concatenaciones de strings (Concat o +) para pasar todos los parametros como cadenas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Me parece que esto no responde la pregunta. Básicamente explicas cómo leer la llave de configuración... pero no cómo acceder a los archivos.